# How to make a layout design like this

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-listview

I'm trying to create a layout like this. My idea is to use gird layout in horizontal way to achieve the design. i don't how to create spacing as in this design. Can anybody help me to do this. The design is giving below. when user complete level. the icon get changed from red highlighted to yellow one. can we use recycle view or listview ? [image]

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

This question was interesting and after some testing, not sure if my solution is perfect felt more like a workaround but i was able to achieve a similar layout, making use of `RecyclerView` and `GridLayoutManager`.

Firstly, created 2 rectangle vector drawables one for normal holders and for when its highlighted.

like the sample below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<padding android:left="2dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp" />
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

In the layout for recyclerview holder created a view inside a `FrameLayout` with this default background. Use `android:scaleX` and `android:scaleY` to scale the view down a bit, and `android:rotation="45"` to achieve the diamond shape. Be sure to use margins and padding so that the background doesn't get clipped on rotation

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:scaleX="0.85"
        android:scaleY="0.85"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/diamond_default"
        android:rotation="45" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_cup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cup"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"  />
</FrameLayout>
```

you can show your cup/trophy in the `ImageView`

Rest setup the Horizontal recyclerview with `GridLayoutManager` having `spanCount` 2.

Next you need to create a class for decorating the spacing by extending `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`

The sample one i used is below :

```
public class RecyclerViewItemSpacingDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private int spaceLeft;
private int spaceRight;
private int spaceTop;
private int spaceBottom;

public RecyclerViewItemSpacingDecoration(int spaceLeft, int spaceRight, int spaceTop, int spaceBottom) {
    this.spaceLeft = spaceLeft;
    this.spaceRight = spaceRight;
    this.spaceTop = spaceTop;
    this.spaceBottom = spaceBottom;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                           RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if(parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) % 2 == 0) {
        outRect.left = spaceLeft;
        outRect.right = spaceRight;
        outRect.top = spaceTop;
        outRect.bottom = spaceBottom;
    } else {
        outRect.left = 0;
        outRect.right = 0;
        outRect.top = 0;
        outRect.bottom = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Use position % 2 check to add spacing to only one row of the gridLayout.
Then add this to your recyclerview using `rv.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewItemSpacingDecoration(148, -148, 112, -112));` The spacing will need to be adjusted according to your view size.

You'll need to add `android:paddingEnd="84dp"  android:clipToPadding="false"` similar codes to prevent recyclerview clipping at the end because of added decoration space.

And whenever a viewHolder needs to be highlighted inside `onBindViewHolder()` you can set the highlighted background and scale it up to get the desired effect from `viewHolder.view.setBackground(viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.diagonal_highlighted));
                viewHolder.view.setScaleX(1.05f);
                viewHolder.view.setScaleY(1.05f);`  You may add animations for this scaling for better effects.

Finally achieve something like this:

[image: sample layout]

Hope this answer is of help in some way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create this kind of shape (the rhombus) with vector drawable, and the spacing using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` with recycler view.